# ManyToOne reference with encrypted fields gives doesn't exist error using Jasypt

Tags: hibernate, spring, encryption, many-to-one, jasypt

I have a problem on the following situation:

In my Spring, Hibernate application I got a User Entity and a UserCategory Entity. The table of the user entity got a username as identifier. This indentifierfield can't be encrypted because this table is also used by an older program without the possibility to do this.

To make a ManyToOne reference from UserCategory to User I need a field in the UserCategory table with the unique username of a User. What I want to do is to encrypt the username in the UserCategory table using Jasypt. And of course this work:

```
    @Type(type="encryptedString") 
    @ManyToOne 
    @JoinColumn(name = "username", insertable=false, updatable=false)   
    @ForeignKey(name = "none") 
    public User getUser(){ 
            return this.user; 
    } 
    public void setUser(User user ){ 
            this.user = user; 
    }
```

But after putting the username encrypted in the UserCategory table I can't use this record because Hibernate can't make a reference to the User on encrypted field: 
You will get the following error:

```
"No row with the given identifier exists: com.foo.bar.models.User#M9LgndiyCsVGqfVRVblb3A=="
```

This is a logical error, but do you know a good solution. In think the code need something to first decrypt and then try to make the reference. But I'm stuck on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood how to use a custom user type and, as [I commented in my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282245/hibernate-encrypted-reference-by-relations-on-usernames/3282341#3282341), you are NOT supposed to declare the custom type at **the association level** here, you are supposed to use it at the attribute level i.e. on the `username` attribute of the `User` entity.

This is actually explained in the documentation (pasted from Google Cache as the Jasypt site seems to be currently down):

> #### [Integrating Jasypt with Hibernate 3](http://www.jasypt.org/hibernate3.html)
>
> Jasypt provides an integration package
>   (`org.jasypt.hibernate.type`) which
>   provides several Hibernate `UserType`
>   implementations **to allow one or
>   several of the properties in a mapped
>   Hibernate entity to be declared as
>   being of an encrypted type**. Types
>   allowed to be stored encrypted include
>   strings, binaries (byte arrays),
>   numeric types, booleans and dates.
>
> Persistence of those properties will
>   be done in an encrypted manner, but in
>   a completely transparent way for the
>   application.
>
> This can be useful for encrypting
>   personal data, private messages, etc,
>   so that it is avoided that anyone with
>   read access to the "critical" tables
>   can read all of its contents.
>
> For encryption at Hibernate, jasypt
>   uses its password-based encryption
>   capabilities, and any encryptor object
>   implementing PBEStringEncryptor,
>   PBEByteEncryptor,
>   PBEBigIntegerEncryptor or
>   PBEBigDecimalEncryptor can be used to
>   encrypt data, even encryptors created
>   by the user.
>
> But **encryption sets a limitation on
>   your Hibernate usage**: security
>   standards establish that two different
>   encryption operations on the same data
>   should not return the same value (due
>   to the use of a random salt). **Because
>   of this, none of the fields that are
>   set to be encrypted when persisted can
>   be a part of a WHERE clause in your
>   search queries for the entity they
>   belong to**.

So, to sum up, 1) the `@Type` annotation should be applied to the `username` and 2) you won't be able to use the `username` as primary key (since it can't be part of a join as mentioned in the last paragraph above).

This means that you'll need something like this (assuming you declared the appropriate `@TypeDef`):

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Type(type="encryptedString") 
    private String username;

    ...
}
```

And modify the `ManyToOne` association accordingly.

Comment: Thx again for your answer. I was aware of the information you give, but I thought there was maybe an alternative so I can use it on the way I give in my example. But I already was afraid that couldn't work with Jasypt. And unfortunately I can't use the example you give with a auto generated value id. But thanks anyway for your response. I will look further for a different approach or a other framework

Comment: @michel: You're welcome. If I way, you should try to give a maximum of details on your constraints when asking a question, this would really help to get the best possible answer. That said, if Jasypt can't work for you, you can maybe build a custom solution using a custom type as I suggested in your other question (but use it on the field, not on the association).